# Why doesn't this code draw white text?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This code doesn't draw white text, why?

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"System" size:13];
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, font, NSFontAttributeName, [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

[button.title drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attrs];
```

Comment: Then what color does it draw in?

Comment: it draws standard black color

Comment: If button is an instance of your own class, there's no way we could know the answer. I *presume* drawInRect: is making an NSMutableString, but you don't say that.  And I *presume* it calls your drawRect to draw it, but you don't tell us that, either.  And, as another commenter said, "System" is unlikely to be a font name, so font might be nil or might fall back to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>(Assuming the [cocoa] tag doesn't mean cocoa touch)</sub>

It's because NSButton is likely overriding the choice you've made to draw it's text in when it's `-drawRect:` gets called again.  You can apply the attributes you've given in that dictionary to an NSAttributedString and call `setAttributedTitle:` to keep your style choices around.

If you need more fine-grain control over text rendering, either edit and move your logic into `-drawRect:` if it isn't already there, or provide an NSTextField or NSTextView as appropriate.

The main problem with the code you've provided is that @"System" isn't a font name.

Comment: button is not NSButton, it's my own class. I am painting over simple NSView!

Comment: Then why do you have a variable named button?  And why the heck isn't this code in `-drawRect:`?

Comment: this code right there, in drawRect. Show me different way how to draw colored text in drawRect?

Comment: Perhaps consider rendering it in an NSTextField, then.